How to implement a handler for an unauthenticated request to a js file?
I want to block a js file from being returned for unauthenticated and non admin requests (eg http://test.com/test/test.js). I decided to implement a handler, the service is running on a IIS 10 Integrated Mode. Do I need a handler declaration at server side or only at code side? Let me know the actual implementation of the handler.
The project being used is ASP.NET Framework 4.8

What authentication method are you using?

Are you looking for some configuration similar to this? Or only implement this via handler?
